# Is there accepted terminology for multisets of vectors that are "as independent as possible"?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

Let $V$ denote a finite-dimensional real vector space. Suppose $A$ is a multiset of elements of $V$. Then if $\mathrm{card}(A) > \mathrm{dim}(V)$, it follows that $A$ cannot be linearly independent. Nonetheless, it may be the case that these vectors are "as independent as possible," meaning that for every submultiset $B$ of $A$ with $\mathrm{card}(A)=\mathrm{dim}(V),$ it holds that $B$ is linearly independent. For instance, the multiset $$\left\{[1 \;\; 0], [1/2 \;\; 1/2], [0 \;\; 1]\right\}$$ is "as independent as possible," whereas $$\left\{[1 \;\; 1], [1/2 \;\; 1/2], [0 \;\; 1]\right\}$$ is not.

> **Question.** Is there accepted terminology for multisets of vectors that are "as independent as possible"?

Comment: Why do you phrase this question in terms of multisets?

Comment: What have multisets have to do with this?

Comment: @RobArthan, most textbooks seem not to realize it, but things go wrong when thinking about linear independence using subsets. In particular, we'd like the following to be true: let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ denote a linear transform. Then for all subsets $A$ of $X$, if $A$ is linearly dependent, then so too is $f(A)$. In other words, if $f(A)$ is linearly independent, then so too is $A$. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite hold. The problem is solved by using multisets instead of sets. So to answer copper.hat's question; nothing, except that subsets aren't the right tool in much of linear algebra.

Comment: @goblin But if $A$ is a multiset in which some element is repeated, it cannot possibly satisfy the "as linearly independent as possible" condition that you describe, unless the vector space has dimension $1$ (in which case the condition is trivially satisfied by every (multi)set not containing the zero vector).

Comment: I don't understand your point about "linear transforms": we don't want linear independence to be preserved under all linear transformations (which under the usual definitions includes singular linear transformations).

Comment: @kccu, that observation is precisely why this confusion has existed for so long. You can *almost* get away with subsets, because any multiset with repeated elements is necessarily dependent. But you can't *quite* get away with subsets, as my comment demonstrates.

Comment: @RobArthan, I wrote that *dependence* should be preserved under linear transforms; independence should be reflected.

Comment: If any element is repeated then the resulting collection can never be linearly independent in the sense described above. I don't follow the polemic on multisets and linear algebra.

Comment: @goblin To answer your original question, I don't know of any standard name for such multisets.

Comment: I suspect from your comments that  what you don't like about the standard definitiosn is that a linear transformation can identify two vectors and so turn a linearly dependent set into a linearly independent set. I don't think anyone apart from you thinks this is a problem (and if I did, my thoughts would be to work with indexed sets rather than multisets to solve it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you are looking for may be that of [general position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position), where no subset has any more dependence relations than necessary. This means that if $k\leq\dim(V)$, any subset with $k$ elements will span a $k$-dimensional subspace.

"General position" can also be applied in other situations both within and outside of linear algebra (indeed, the linked Wikipedia article focuses mainly on algebraic geometry) and vaguely means that there are no "coincidences." Sticking with linear algebra for the moment, we can say that a set of $2$-dimensional subspaces is in general position if there are no unnecessary intersections. In $3$-dimensional space two planes can't help but intersect in a line. Any set of two planes in $3$-space is in general position, but a set of three planes is only in general position if they do not all intersect in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a linear map rather than a set (so, the canonical linear map from a vector space which has $A$ as a basis to $V$), you can say that the map has "full rank".  That is, it has the maximal possible rank that it could have.  I don't know how common it is to use "full rank" to describe a set rather than a map, but it seems natural enough to do so and I think that the meaning would be immediately understood.